# Refactoring a Tornado Request Handler

Tags: python, tornado, yield

So I have repeating code that I do for many GETs -- checking whether the response was cached previously and returning that if it is available.

The code I'd like to get working looks like this:

```
class Handler(web.RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def get_cache(self):
        try:
            response = yield gen.Task(get_redis)
        except:
            logging.log()
        if response:
            self.finish(response)
            raise gen.Return()


    @gen.coroutine
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.get_cache()

        response = do_sql_get()

        self.set_cache(key, response)
        self.finish(response)
```

What's happening now is that it gets the cache if there but continues running the rest of the code in `self.get`. That it does this makes sense to me, but I'm not sure how to refactor it properly with it stopping as soon as `self.finish` is called in the `self.get_cache` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_cache` should return a value that indicates whether it finished the request or not (or it should return the cached data and leave it to the caller to finish the request).  I would do one of the following:

```
@gen.coroutine
def serve_from_cache(self):
  response = yield gen.Task(get_redis)
  if response:
      self.finish(response)
      raise gen.Return(True)
  else:
      raise gen.Return(False)

@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
  if (yield self.serve_from_cache()):
    return
  # do work
  yield self.set_cache(...)
```

or

```
@gen.coroutine
def get_cache(self):
    return yield gen.Task(get_redis)


@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    resp = yield self.get_cache()
    if resp:
      self.finish(resp)
      return
    # do work...
```